# Popover displaying inaccurate information inside ForEach

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I'm having a problem where I have a ForEach loop inside a NavigationView. When I click the Edit button, and then click the pencil image at the right hand side on each row, I want it to display the text variable we are using from the ForEach loop. But when I click the pencil image for the text other than **test123**, it still displays the text **test123** and I have absolutely no idea why.

[Here's](https://streamable.com/zd1olp) a video. Why is this happening?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestPopOver: View {
    
    private var stringObjects = ["test123", "helloworld", "reddit"]
    
    @State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    @State private var showThemeEditor = false
        
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.stringObjects, id: \.self) { text in
                    NavigationLink( destination: HStack{Text("Test!")}) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(text)
                            Spacer()
                            if self.editMode.isEditing {
                                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle").imageScale(.large)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        if self.editMode.isEditing {
                                            self.showThemeEditor = true
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .popover(isPresented: $showThemeEditor) {
                        CustomPopOver(isShowing: $showThemeEditor, text: text)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Reproduce Editing Bug!")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)

        }
    }
}

struct CustomPopOver: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack() {
                Spacer()
                Button("Cancel") {
                    self.isShowing = false
                }.padding()
            }
            Divider()
            List {
                Section {
                    Text(text)
                }
            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common issue (especially since iOS 14) that gets run into a lot with `sheet` but affects `popover` as well.

You can avoid it by using `popover(item:)` rather than `isPresented`. In this scenario, it'll actually use the latest values, not just the one that was present when then view first renders or when it is first set.

```
struct EditItem : Identifiable { //this will tell it what sheet to present
    var id = UUID()
    var str : String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private var stringObjects = ["test123", "helloworld", "reddit"]
    
    @State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    @State private var editItem : EditItem? //the currently presented sheet -- nil if no sheet is presented
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.stringObjects, id: \.self) { text in
                    NavigationLink( destination: HStack{Text("Test!")}) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(text)
                            Spacer()
                            if self.editMode.isEditing {
                                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle").imageScale(.large)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        if self.editMode.isEditing {
                                            self.editItem = EditItem(str: text) //set the current item
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .popover(item: $editItem) { item in //item is now a reference to the current item being presented
                        CustomPopOver(text: item.str)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Reproduce Editing Bug!")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)

        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct CustomPopOver: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack() {
                Spacer()
                Button("Cancel") {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }.padding()
            }
            Divider()
            List {
                Section {
                    Text(text)
                }
            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
        
    }
}
```

I also opted to use the `presentationMode` environment property to dismiss the popover, but you *could* pass the `editItem` binding and set it to `nil` as well (`@Binding var editItem : EditItem?` and `editItem = nil`). The former is just a little more idiomatic.

Comment: Can confirm, “isPresented” is just broken in macOS whereas “item” works almost great (sometimes just doesn’t do anything but most of the time works)

Comment: Thank you so much. Your assistance was right on the money!